# Can I override the way that a bootswatch theme works?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I am using the [Bootswatch Lux theme](https://bootswatch.com/lux/) on my Django based site, but bold text just appears as little different from normal text.

Is it possible/wise to change the css is some way to produce a greater differentiation between normal and bold text?

Answer (score 0):

If you use font-weight: bold, there are not many things to change because that's the default bold of the font you use. So there are 2 options, one option is to change the font and the other is to declare a new class (say bold) and give a darker color to create a more clear difference. But if you are talking about headings and buttons you can go to _variables.scss and change the font-weight to what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have mentioned that I'm using Django, so I can't really put text classes at various arbitrary points. I've updated my question

Comment: I've never used django to be honest by as far as I can see you can declare and use whatever class you want. _variables.scss is in your bootwatch lux theme. Locate it and make your changes there except if you import it with cdn.

Comment: I am using cdn. I thought maybe there was some way I could override the css just for the one element

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you give me more information? Do you already use some class for bold? If yes then which one is it? If no, then you have to create the same class in your css in order to override it.